# Is there (and what are) a differences in developing in html5 and by using phonegap?

Tags: android, html, cordova

What is the difference if we develop android apps in pure html5 without using phonegap libraries and what if we use Phonegap? This might sound noob but I'm really not getting the connection between these two?

Why do I need phonegap? Why not just creating html5 files and provide the path to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HTML5 and PhoneGap you can implement different kinds of applications:

- Mobile applications using HTML5. You will need a server to back up your application and the users will run it through the device's browser.
- Native application using HTML5 and WebView. Using a server isn't necessary. In this case you write HTML5 code (HTML, CSS, Javascript) and you use a WebView to display it. You can interact with Java using a special interface.
- PhoneGap makes the above case easier. You don't need to know the details of WebView. You need PhoneGap APIs to interact with the phone's resources. As an added bonus you can easily port the application to other platforms. PhoneGap also creates native applications.

Answer (score 1):

PhoneGap give you a layer of abstraction so that you app is going to have access to non browserView accessible functionality like the camera for example.
And those will be the same on all mobile plateforme.

Comment: can we use our own html5,js files in phonegap or the code is different?

Comment: If it has not changed I've not used it in a while. The way it work is that you have an index.html which is served in the view using the `file://` protocol rather than running a tiny web server. Which lead to some limitations. But beside that this is just a static web app server in a full screen webview.

Answer (score 1):

You can create application with pure html5 with webview and piece of java methods used to handle mobile events like Calling, Messaging, Sensors, etc,.

When you are using phonegap libraries, no need to do much work with java methods. The phonegap libraries will handle the java and you can only work with html5 and java script with little bit help of jquery mobile framework. All mobile events you can call directly in the javascript of html page.